# How to drag a SVG to start an animation?

Tags: svg

I have made a beer tap where you can click on the handle to start the animation.

I would like to change it so that you have to click and drag the handle back to start the animation.  How would something like this be achieved?

If you cannot drag to activate the animation. How can I speed up the pulling back animation and freeze it at the pulled back position until complete?

I would also like to know why the small bubbles do not stop and reset when the handle is clicked again like the rests of the animation?

[JsFiddle to SVG](https://jsfiddle.net/rq9dpc6z/)

```
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="233.816px" height="643.371px" viewBox="0 0 233.816 643.371" enable-background="new 0 0 233.816 643.371"
     xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="pour" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#C06028" d="M134.793,600.695c0,2.761-2.239,5-5,5h-5c-2.761,0-5-2.239-5-5
        v-340c0-2.761,2.239-5,5-5h5c2.761,0,5,2.239,5,5V600.695z" opacity="0">
      <set attributeName="opacity" to="1" begin="taphandle.click" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
<animate id="animatePour" dur="0.1s" attributeName="opacity" from="1" to="0" begin="taphandle.click + 4.9s" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
</path>
<g id="beer-glass_1_">
    <g id="beer_1_">
    <linearGradient id="beer-fill-g" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#C06028">
            <animate id="#animateBeer1"attributeName="offset" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" dur="5s" begin="taphandle.click" fill="freeze"/>
          </stop>
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="#C06028">
            <animate id="#animateBeer2" attributeName="offset" values="0;1" repeatCount="1" dur="5s" begin="taphandle.click" fill="freeze"/>
          </stop>       
      </linearGradient>
        <path id="beer-fill" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="url(#beer-fill-g)" d="M80.068,383.621
            c-0.731,4.043,0.561,17.75-0.415,24.842c-2.13,15.49-0.908,28.531,0.895,36.818c2.295,10.549,5.457,21.016,6.568,31.691
            c2.496,23.989,4.08,48.079,5.804,72.144c1.403,19.584,2.343,39.203,3.899,58.773c0.143,1.793,3.068,4.441,5.066,4.832
            c10.412,2.041,20.926,4.717,31.436,4.861c19.596,0.268,39.221-0.885,58.813-1.842c4.91-0.24,9.746-1.992,14.617-3.043
            c2.994-0.645,4.346-2.301,4.535-5.545c1.4-24.098,3.053-48.18,4.475-72.277c1.855-31.391,4.037-62.657,11.771-93.394
            c1.838-7.306,3.26-29.661,1.873-44.111c-0.568-5.906-0.922-8.063-0.717-11.75L80.068,383.621z"/>       
        <g id="beer-bubbles">
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="108.337" cy="631.698" r="5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="taphandle.click + 3s"
                        dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>       
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="133.793" cy="630.698" r="4">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="taphandle.click + 2s"
                        dur="3s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="181.17" cy="636.198" r="4.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="taphandle.click + 5.5s"
                        dur="1s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="204.337" cy="622.622" r="5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="taphandle.click + 3.5s"
                        dur="1.5s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="164.003" cy="626.622" r="4">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="taphandle.click + 2s"
                        dur="3s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="122.293" cy="620.122" r="2.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="taphandle.click + 5s"
                        dur="1s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="187.17" cy="624.122" r="1.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="taphandle.click + 4s"
                        dur="1.5s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="149.837" cy="634.198" r="2.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="taphandle.click + 5s"
                        dur="2s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
            <circle opacity="0.9" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" cx="104.837" cy="619.122" r="1.5">
                        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        type="translate"
                        from="0 0"
                        to="0 -250"
                        begin="taphandle.click + 2s"
                        dur="3s"
                        repeatCount="indefinite"/>
                            </circle>
        </g>
    </g>
    <path id="glass-light" opacity="0.4" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M99.138,412.893
        c-7.283-0.969-7.33-0.976-8.471,6.327c-2.135,13.66,1.293,26.705,3.902,39.969c3.234,16.442,5.487,33.095,7.663,49.723
        c1.531,11.703,2.247,23.514,3.282,35.28c0.293,3.328,1.399,5.123,4.586,3.42c0-10.257,0.45-20.234-0.104-30.155
        c-0.844-15.104-1.839-30.24-3.801-45.228c-1.547-11.831-5.221-23.38-6.855-35.205C98.267,429.25,99.138,421.208,99.138,412.893z"/>
    <path id="glass_1_" opacity="1" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M234.15,406.965
        c-0.014-0.075-2.215-51.691-2.229-51.76c-0.605-2.835-3.385-1.696-5-0.793c-0.01,0.156,2.971,52.208,2.963,52.364
        c-0.613,11.878,0.381,24.086-2.236,34.485c-7.735,30.736-9.917,62.003-11.771,93.394c-1.423,24.097-3.074,48.18-4.476,72.277
        c-0.188,3.244-1.54,4.9-4.534,5.545c-4.871,1.05-9.707,2.803-14.617,3.043c-19.592,0.957-39.218,2.109-58.813,1.841
        c-10.51-0.145-21.024-2.819-31.437-4.86c-1.998-0.391-4.923-3.039-5.066-4.833c-1.557-19.57-2.497-39.188-3.899-58.772
        c-1.724-24.065-3.307-48.154-5.804-72.145c-1.111-10.676-4.273-21.143-6.567-31.69c-2.504-11.511-2.756-25.218-0.936-37.101
        c0.124-0.809,0.32-52.052,0.463-52.843c-2.516-1.228-3.44-0.6-4.063,0.005c-0.246,0.239-1.166,52.796-1.186,52.916
        c-0.515,2.971-1.537,8.079-1.939,10.334c0,4,0,8,0,12c0.937,5.031,1.485,10.173,2.876,15.076
        c6.298,22.195,8.559,44.973,10.181,67.853c1.175,16.572,2.348,33.146,3.4,49.726c1.293,20.367,2.598,40.735,3.618,61.116
        c0.412,8.237,2.684,12.077,10.593,14.702c3.285,1.091,6.725,1.868,10.156,2.33c6.703,0.902,13.448,1.483,20.176,2.197
        c13.333,0,26.666,0,40,0c3.264-0.371,6.563-0.554,9.785-1.15c7.938-1.472,15.993-2.617,23.703-4.901
        c5.107-1.513,7.354-5.948,7.484-11.659c0.27-11.767,0.885-23.535,1.705-35.279c2.328-33.334,4.05-66.737,7.555-99.951
        c2.092-19.845,7.08-39.383,10.768-59.059c0-4.333,0-8.667,0-13C234.539,415.778,234.607,409.392,234.15,406.965z"/>
    <path id="foam" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M227.107,357.142c0.008-0.202,0.029-0.4,0.029-0.604
        c0-8.284-6.715-15-15-15c-1.994,0-3.894,0.397-5.634,1.104c-3.636-3.758-8.724-6.104-14.366-6.104c-2.441,0-4.77,0.459-6.933,1.26
        c-3.116-1.395-6.565-2.177-10.2-2.177c-5.556,0-10.686,1.814-14.836,4.88c-3.33-2.478-7.444-3.963-11.914-3.963
        c-6.477,0-12.217,3.092-15.872,7.865c-3.65-2.085-7.873-3.282-12.377-3.282c-4.183,0-8.122,1.032-11.586,2.848
        c-1.612-0.592-3.346-0.932-5.164-0.932c-5.568,0-10.416,3.041-13.004,7.545c-9.739,1.345-17.246,9.68-17.246,19.789
        c0,11.046,8.954,20,20,20c4.576,0,8.78-1.554,12.15-4.14c4.152,3.071,9.288,4.89,14.85,4.89c2.877,0,5.638-0.492,8.21-1.387
        c1.578,0.564,3.269,0.887,5.04,0.887c4.178,0,7.955-1.711,10.674-4.468c3.667,4.21,9.053,6.884,15.075,6.884
        c6.28,0,11.878-2.9,15.545-7.428c0.152,0.003,0.303,0.012,0.455,0.012c0.599,0,1.191-0.029,1.779-0.07
        c2.53,4.71,7.5,7.914,13.221,7.914c4.706,0,8.902-2.171,11.652-5.563c3.542,3.183,8.211,5.135,13.348,5.135
        c11.045,0,20-8.954,20-20C235.003,366.547,231.898,360.795,227.107,357.142z" transform="translate(0, 250)"opacity="0">
        <set attributeName="opacity" to="1" begin="taphandle.click" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
            <animateTransform id="animateFoam"
            attributeName="transform"
            type="translate"
            from="0 250"
            to="0 0"
            begin="taphandle.click"
            dur="5s" fill="freeze"/>
        </path>
</g>
<g id="tap">
    <path id="taphandle" class="handle" fill="#888888" d="M123.077,164.857l-2.97-158.875c0-3.304,6.71-5.982,14.981-5.982
        c8.275,0,14.984,2.678,14.984,5.982l-2.996,160.327h-0.242c1.662,2.89,2.641,6.394,2.641,10.168
        c0,9.914-6.707,17.946-14.983,17.946c-8.273,0-14.982-8.034-14.982-17.946C119.509,172.044,120.853,167.988,123.077,164.857z">
           <animateTransform id="animateHandle"
            attributeName="transform"
            type="rotate"
            from="0 130 160"
            to="-15 130 160"
            begin="taphandle.click"
            dur="5s"/>
        </path>     
    <path id="tap_1_" fill="#999999" d="M174,193.621h-21.575c0-9.914-8.051-17.947-17.979-17.947s-17.979,8.035-17.979,17.947H84.69
        l1.711-28.459c0-0.826-2.685-1.496-5.993-1.496c-3.311,0-5.993,0.67-5.993,1.496l1.711,28.459H47.348l-5.994-5.984v-4.787
        c0-3.963-2.685-7.178-5.993-7.178H17.378c-2.968,0-5.427,2.588-5.902,5.982H5.992c-3.31,0-5.993,2.678-5.992,5.982v47.858
        c0,3.305,2.685,5.981,5.992,5.981h5.483c0.478,3.396,2.937,5.983,5.903,5.983h17.98c3.31,0,5.991-3.215,5.991-7.183V233.7
        l5.993-5.982h38.854l29.595,43.978c1.898,2.707,8.933,1.063,15.711-3.678c6.779-4.738,10.735-10.771,8.838-13.479l-18.758-28.018
        l50.621-2.99c3.309,0,7.791-6.695,7.791-14.957C179.995,200.316,177.312,193.621,174,193.621z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The bubbles don't reset because they never stop (repeatCount="indefinite")

Comment: I don't want them to stop while the glass is full. they must only stop and reset for the next pour. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: end="whatever is appropriate"